# There is no handlers in listener, but hasHandlers() return True

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

I have similar code to the snippet below, and can't figure out why it behaves differently when invoked as standalone script and as listener.
When it is invoked as python script hasHandlers() method returns False as expected, because logger has no handlers.
On the other hand when it is used as a listener to robot script, hasHandlers() method returns True and the handler is not added. Handlers print also shows empty list.
The condition "if not logger.hasHandlers()" is added because without it, it prints same entry multiple times when several tests are executed.

```
def end_test(name, attrs):
    set_logging()
    some_stuff_logging()

def set_logging():
    global logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    print(logger.handlers)
    print ("Has handlers: {}".format(logger.hasHandlers()))
    if not logger.hasHandlers():
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s | %(module)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s")
        stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

def some_stuff_logging():
    /* use logger to print stuff */

if __name__ == '__main__':
    set_logging()
    some_stuff_logging()
```

I can't figure what causes that there is not returned False in hasHandlers method, despite no handlers attached to logger